# Jenkins Pod not coming up when installed using pre-existing PVC

Tags: jenkins, plugins, kubernetes-helm, startup, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to install Jenkins using Helm. Charts used - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrTXx.png))
chart version 4.6.4.

We have another Jenkins which uses a PV that is bound to a disk on GCP. We wanted to backup that disk and spin a new instance using backup. Hence we are trying to install jenkins using that Disk . bound to a PVC and PV.

As per the charts , we only have to specify the PVC name in the values.yaml.  When I give PVC and deploy Jenkins, Pod gets rebooted after every 2 minutes, with below errors.  However, when I dont plug in the PVC in the chart, jenkins startsup successfully.

Is there anything that needs to be fixed when PVCs are used ? Please let me know.

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
2023-09-14 10:03:09.962+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2023-09-14 10:03:10.155+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2023-09-14 10:03:10.325+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-10.0.15; built: 2023-04-11T17:25:14.480Z; git: 68017dbd00236bb7e187330d7585a059610f661d; jvm 11.0.20+8
2023-09-14 10:03:10.943+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2023-09-14 10:03:11.065+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: Session workerName=node0
2023-09-14 10:03:12.019+0000 [id=1]     INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2023-09-14 10:03:12.281+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@375b5b7f{Jenkins v2.414.1,/,file:///var/jenkins_cache/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_cache/war}
2023-09-14 10:03:12.317+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@37883b97{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2023-09-14 10:03:12.352+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started Server@53aad5d5{STARTING}[10.0.15,sto=0] @3392ms
2023-09-14 10:03:12.358+0000 [id=23]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2023-09-14 10:03:12.763+0000 [id=29]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2023-09-14 10:03:13.094+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2023-09-14 10:03:13.696+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jackson 2 API Plugin v2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595 (jackson2-api)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Jackson 2 API Plugin (jackson2-api 2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595)
 - Update required: JAXB plugin (jaxb 2.3.6-1) to be updated to 2.3.8-1 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.705+0000 [id=28]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Metrics Plugin v4.2.18-442.v02e107157925 (metrics)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Metrics Plugin (metrics 4.2.18-442.v02e107157925)
 - Failed to load: Jackson 2 API Plugin (jackson2-api 2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.707+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Support Core Plugin v1204.v7ee88742a_53f (support-core)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Support Core Plugin (support-core 1204.v7ee88742a_53f)
 - Failed to load: Metrics Plugin (metrics 4.2.18-442.v02e107157925)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.711+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jenkins Git client plugin v4.5.0 (git-client)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Jenkins Git client plugin (git-client 4.5.0)
 - Update required: Mina SSHD API :: Core (mina-sshd-api-core 2.8.0-36.v8e25ce90d4b_1) to be updated to 2.10.0-69.v28e3e36d18eb_ or higher
 - Update required: Mina SSHD API :: Common (mina-sshd-api-common 2.8.0-36.v8e25ce90d4b_1) to be updated to 2.10.0-69.v28e3e36d18eb_ or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.722+0000 [id=28]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin ECharts API Plugin v5.3.3-1 (echarts-api)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: ECharts API Plugin (echarts-api 5.3.3-1)
 - Failed to load: Jackson 2 API Plugin (jackson2-api 2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.723+0000 [id=28]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin JUnit Plugin v1143.v8d9a_e3355270 (junit)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: JUnit Plugin (junit 1143.v8d9a_e3355270)
 - Failed to load: ECharts API Plugin (echarts-api 5.3.3-1)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.724+0000 [id=28]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Matrix Project Plugin v772.v494f19991984 (matrix-project)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Matrix Project Plugin (matrix-project 772.v494f19991984)
 - Failed to load: JUnit Plugin (junit 1143.v8d9a_e3355270)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.727+0000 [id=28]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Git plugin v5.1.0 (git)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Git plugin (git 5.1.0)
 - Update required: Token Macro Plugin (token-macro 308.v4f2b_ed62b_b_16) to be updated to 359.vb_cde11682e0c or higher
 - Failed to load: Jenkins Git client plugin (git-client 4.5.0)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1166)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.729+0000 [id=31]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Google Metadata plugin v0.3.1 (google-metadata-plugin)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Google Metadata plugin (google-metadata-plugin 0.3.1)
 - Failed to load: Jackson 2 API Plugin (jackson2-api 2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.731+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Google OAuth Credentials plugin v1.0.9 (google-oauth-plugin)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Google OAuth Credentials plugin (google-oauth-plugin 1.0.9)
 - Failed to load: Jackson 2 API Plugin (jackson2-api 2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.732+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Jenkins Mercurial plugin v2.16.2 (mercurial)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Jenkins Mercurial plugin (mercurial 2.16.2)
 - Failed to load: Matrix Project Plugin (matrix-project 772.v494f19991984)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1166)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.734+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Google Authenticated Source plugin v0.4 (google-source-plugin)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Google Authenticated Source plugin (google-source-plugin 0.4)
 - Failed to load: Google Metadata plugin (google-metadata-plugin 0.3.1)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.738+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Nodes and Processes v1289.v4d3e7b_01546b_ (workflow-durable-task-step)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Nodes and Processes (workflow-durable-task-step 1289.v4d3e7b_01546b_)
 - Update required: Durable Task Plugin (durable-task 496.va67c6f9eefa7) to be updated to 513.vc48a_a_075a_d93 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.739+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Kubernetes Client API Plugin v6.8.1-224.vd388fca_4db_3b_ (kubernetes-client-api)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Kubernetes Client API Plugin (kubernetes-client-api 6.8.1-224.vd388fca_4db_3b_)
 - Failed to load: Jackson 2 API Plugin (jackson2-api 2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.740+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Kubernetes Credentials Plugin v0.11 (kubernetes-credentials)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Kubernetes Credentials Plugin (kubernetes-credentials 0.11)
 - Failed to load: Jackson 2 API Plugin (jackson2-api 2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:177)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
2023-09-14 10:03:13.742+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Model API v2.2114.v2654ca_721309 (pipeline-model-api)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Model API (pipeline-model-api 2.2114.v2654ca_721309)
 - Failed to load: Jackson 2 API Plugin (jackson2-api 2.15.2-350.v0c2f3f8fc595)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:988)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:555)
```

When I remove existing PVC and simply install the chart, then Jenkins is up and running.
Are the plugins , that are part of PVC-->Disk,  failing to load ?  I know PVC is bound to the pod, but How can I verify if it is mounted to the pod ? We are not mentioning any mount for PVC here.
Can someone help point us in the right direction ..?

Comment: helm chart used  is the default chart that comes with version 4.6.4 (helm repo add jenkins https://charts.jenkins.io)

Comment: I exec into the pod, and I see the plugins folder and /var/jenkins_home mounted as expected.